# Inspect serialized file content

Tags: java, software-rec, file-format, viewer

I have a file which apparently contains serialized structures. The first 26 bytes contain the string "java.util.HashMap", so I am sure that this file holds serialized data.

Is there is nice tool maybe with a simple UI, where I can show the structured data?

I googled for it for a while, but I didn't find any proper resources. It should run preferred on Windows. Linux would be fine too but is overhead for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### jdeserialize

There is tool from Google called "jdeserialize":

> jdeserialize is a library that interprets Java serialized objects --
> the data generated by an ObjectOutputStream. **It also comes with a
> command-line tool** that can generate compilable class declarations,
> extract block data, and print textual representations of instance
> values.

[Project site of jdeserialize](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jdeserialize/)
[Git repository of jdeserialize](https://github.com/frohoff/jdeserialize/tree/master/jdeserialize)

---

### Serialysis

There is also a Java library called "Serialysis", that can be used to generate human-readable output of a serialized object, like so:

```
SEntity sint = SerialScan.examine(new Integer(5));
System.out.println(sint);
```

...produces this output:

```
SObject(java.lang.Integer) {
  value = Prim(int){5}
}
```

[Explanation of how Serialysis works](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/emcmanus/2007/06/12/disassembling-serialized-java-objects)
[Git repository of Serialysis](https://github.com/frohoff/serialysis)

---

**Since both projects are written in Java, you can use them in both Windows and Linux.**

Comment: Amazing tool, looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Since I was not sure how to compile it you can find the compiled jar at https://code.google.com/archive/p/jdeserialize/downloads

Comment: Update 2023: jdeserialize and Serialysis seem to no longer be maintained. I had a NullPointerException with jdeserialize, so it may be totally obsolete. I had more luck with SerializationDumper: https://github.com/NickstaDB/SerializationDumper

Comment: Serialysis is old, but still worked as described for me. The latest version 0.9 is hosted on [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.eamonnmcmanus/serialysis/0.9).